# PHP - Getting a float variable internal value

Tags: php, floating-point-precision

I am trying to establish the delta I need when doing float comparison in PHP. **I want to take a closer look at my variables to see the difference.**

I have 2 computed variables, $a, $b.

```
$a = some_function();

$b = some_other_function();
```

How can I see the exact number which PHP uses?

I want to compare them with this formula, where I need to specify the delta:

```
$delta = 0.00001;
if (abs($a-$b) < $delta) {
  echo "identical";
}
```

var_dump($a, $b) returns 1.6215; 1.6215. but I know that they are not exactly equal because

```
var_dump($a === $b);
```

evaluates to false;

Why doesn't `var_dump()` print the internal value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP, the printed values of floating point numbers are dependent on PHP configuration "precision".

You can change that with:

```
ini_set('precision', YOUR_DESIRED_PRECISION_AS_INTEGER);
```

For example with with:

```
ini_set('precision', 18);
```

Your numbers may display something like:

> float 1.62149999999999994
>
> float 1.6214999999999995

So now the difference between them is clearer.

So your delta may be: $delta = 0.00000000000001; It really depends of the precision you are looking for.

If you need to do exact mathematical calculations, do have a look at the [BC Math Functions.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

---

**References / Sources**

[PHP - Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.float.php)

[PHP - Floating point numbers - User Contributed Notes - deminy at deminy dot net](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.float.php#110766)

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/r2sWP5vc)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit your configuration file... you could use the `round(val, precision)` in your `some_function()` and `some_other_function()`. That way you can return the results to the precision you want. Check:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php