# PHP division returns different result (Linux/Windows)

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache, division

I make a simple division using php. Then I test the result in a windows machine running apache and in a linux machine running apache as well.

```
 WINDOWS: 1/15 returns 0.066666666666667
 LINUX: 1/15 returns   0.0666666666667
```

Any suggestions why this is happening? Is it php, apache or OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, [the size of a PHP float is platform-dependent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), so you should not make any assumptions if you want portable code.

However, the difference you see might also be caused by a difference in configuration settings. The [*printed value* of a floating-point value depends on the `precision` setting](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.float.php#110766).

Related:

- [PHP - Getting a float variable internal value, Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800457/87698)

Answer (score 0):

php config. floating point precision settings. number of decimal places option.